# Windows 10 not search host name in DNS when I ping if no dot at end?

Tags: dns, windows-10, window

I have some simple problem which is very typical but not solved in internet - I study 20 solutions or more and all not works (maybe 10 on StackOverflow, ... and Microsoft pages). The most of solutions are wrong (suggest to do not need things). Please do not copy these solutions or refer if you are not understand what they do :)

I have Windows 10 and try to us dns names to search computers but it not works as it expected.

```
ping etcd-1
Ping request could not find host etcd-1. Please check the name and try again.
```

What Wireshark see ... - Windows 10 do no question to DNS (I added .suffix "." in TCP 4/6). Windows 10 do broadcast?

[image]

```
>ping etcd-1.

Pinging etcd-1 [192.168.50.72] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.50.72: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.50.72: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.50.72: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.50.72: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.50.72:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

What Wireshark see ... - Windows 10 do question to DNS but why now?

[image]

What is wrong with this configuration?
Why Windows not use DNS for `etcd-1` but for `etcd-1.`?

`nslookup etcd-1` works!

What is my suffix configuration:

[image]

This is WINS:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this command to clear cache:

```
c:\>ipconfig /flushdns
```